# AngularJS - then() method not being called after reload button click

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, rest

I previously had an issue with variables being undefined due to the asynchronous nature of AJAX.  I have that issue resolved, however, now I have a new issue.  I have the following code:

```
$scope.cities = [
    {name: 'Phoenix,US'},
    {name: 'Atlanta,US'},
    {name: 'Honolulu,US'}
];

$scope.items = [];
$scope.reload = function() {

    alert("Reload clicked");

    var promises = [];

    angular.forEach($scope.cities, function(city) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        delete $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
        $http.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + city.name).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            alert("success");
            deferred.resolve(data);

        });
        promises.push(deferred.promise);
    });

    return $q.all(promises);
};

//not being called after reload button is clicked
$scope.reload().then(function(data) {
    $scope.name0 = data[0].name;
    alert($scope.name0);
);
```

My `$scope.reload` gets called both on the initial page load as well as when clicking on my reload button.  However `scope.reload().then(function(data))` isn't being called after clicking on my reload button; it only gets called on the initial page load, even though `$scope.reload` does get called (as tested with my alert statements).

Could anyone tell me what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure the ajax request is successful?

Comment: Yes (I just tested it right now with an alert statement inside).

Comment: Just to be sure, try adding a second argument to the `then` call with an error callback, and reject the deferred on error. Also add some logs when you resolve each deferred and make sure you see that message for each city you want the weather for.

Comment: So, how would I do that?  I am new to AngularJS, so could you please help out?

Comment: Well you have "success" being alerted - do you see that three times?

Comment: Just confirming is this line of code inside your click handler? `$scope.reload().then(function(data) {`

Comment: Yes, I see it three times.

Comment: This is my click handler: `<button ng-click="reload();">Reload</button>`

Comment: But `reload` function is returning a different promise object each time.. the `then()` was for the first time `reload` ran. You need to create another click handler which calls `reload` function again and attaches `then` on the returned promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put the `then()` function inside the `reload()` function.

**Working fiddle**
I created [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xd4zn/) for you to show you.

I moved this code:

```
$q.all(promises).then(function(data) {
    $scope.answer = data;
});
```

And put it inside your `reload` function.

```
$scope.reload = function () {
    var promises = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.cities, function (city) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        delete $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
        $http.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + city.name).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            deferred.resolve(data);
        });
        promises.push(deferred.promise);
    });

    // This block here:
    $q.all(promises).then(function(data) {
        $scope.answer = data;
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will make a difference, but you don't really need to create new promises manually inside the loop. $http already returns a promise you can use:

```
var promises = [];

angular.forEach($scope.cities, function(city) {
    delete $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
    var promise = $http.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + city.name);
    promise.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        alert("success");

    });
    promises.push(promise);
});
```